# Installing Qt libraries on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I'm trying to install the Qt 4.8.3 precompiled libraries downloaded from http://qt-project.org/downloads on my OS X 10.6 machine. Unfortunately the package doesn't seem to actually install any libraries (although it claims to do so in the readme)

I've read loads of instructions of how to configure and build Qt from source but these are precompiled, as in 'you don't have to compile them yourself'. So I must be missing something.

Is there anyone out there who knows how to actually install Qt on OS X
so that it is possible to link against them -without- building the whole thing from source.

Thanks

Comment: How do you find out it's not installed? And what versions of OS X and Qt?

Comment: From my experience I suggest switching to Qt 4.7.3 on OSX

Comment: @Stephen Chu: I go to the paths referenced in the documentation (usr/local/Trolltech/, usr/Qt4.8/bin and usr/bin) and look for any binaries that I can find. The Trolltech folder is not there, the usr/Qt4.8 folder merely contains an 'mkspecs' folder and the usr/bin contains qtLucene.dylib but none of the other libraries)

Comment: @linello, I can't unfortunately since 4.8 is used on our other platforms so we are locked to 4.8. Although I suspect I wouldn't find the binaries in the 4.7 version either. I'm positive I'm missing something vital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt frameworks are located in /Library/Frameworks/.

When you start the Qt.mpkg in Installer. The Welcome Screen has the following text:

After a successful install, you can find most new things in /Developer. Specifically things will be located in the following places:

```
•   Qt Designer, Qt Linguist: /Developer/Applications/Qt
•   Qt Documentation: /Developer/Documentation/Qt
•   Qt Examples: /Developer/Examples/Qt
•   Qt Plugins: /Developer/Applications/Qt/Plugins
•   Qt Frameworks: /Library/Frameworks
•   Qt Libraries: /usr/lib
•   qmake, moc, uic, etc.: /Developer/Tools/Qt (symlink to /usr/bin)
•   Uninstall script: /Developer/Tools/uninstall-qt.py
```

These should help you out.

Comment: Ah, Frameworks. Got it. That should help me build. A follow up question then: For distribution of runtime I would need the dylib files and they are not found in /usr/lib. Are they hidden in the frameworks or somewhere else?

Comment: Look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html It gives information about this and a handy tool you can use.

Comment: I'm using QT5.5 and Frameworks got installed in the ~/QT/ folder.  Can I just copy them to /Library/Frameworks?  Sounds fishy.  I'm trying to develop an application from source and can't use macdeployqt

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have downloaded the compiled libraries, all you should need to do is locate them in Qt Creator preferences. Go to:

Preferences->Build & Run->Qt Versions

Click add, it will ask you to locate the qmake executable for your Qt library version. Mine happens to be located at:

/Users/MyUserName/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/bin/qmake

As long as you know where you have put your downloaded libraries you should be able to locate the file. Then all you need to do is go to Projects on the Qt Creator sidebar and select your Qt version from the drop down.